# What is the meaning of "I got you"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does

> I got you

mean?

Does it mean

> Ok, I understood what you said

or

> Hey, I know that you did that?

If they are both correct, when should we use which?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meaning depends on the context. In (at least American) slang, saying "I got you" means either "I get what you're saying" or "I've got your back".

In child games of tag, saying "I got you!" means that you caught someone.

Comment: Or romantically: *"I'm so glad I've got you."*  Or friendship: *"You're the only one I've got / We've got each other"*  Or cornering someone: *"I've got you now!"*

Comment: @BlueRaja, wicked username. There's also "I got you babe" - Sonny & Cher

Answer (score 7):

We need some context to be absolutely sure of the phrase, but it often means: "I understand what you're saying."  The "got" has to do with "getting" understanding of the other person's words.  So saying you "got" someone is short for saying you received what they were trying to convey.

More literally, it could be used to mean "I have hold of you" or "I touched you", but I'm not sure that applies in this case, because you felt the need to ask.

Comment: ? Why totally silent on the other meaning?

Answer (score 3):

One meaning is the one "*used to express satisfaction at having captured or defeated someone or uncovered their faults*", also intended as not literal; You can see an example in [The longest yard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QhNLMog7Ho) trailer. Look from the minute 1:32 to roughly 1:40.

The other ones are the ones that @drm65 and @simchona highlighted.

Comment: drm?͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Answer (score -1):

It means I support you.  As in I got your back.

Comment: @tchrist the user is repeating the sentence in simonchona's answer, "I've got your back".

Comment: @Mari-LouA “I’ve got” ≠ “I got”. :)