# Do "You see me?" and "You get me?" mean "Do you understand what I mean?"

Tags: american-english, british-english, synonyms

Sometimes after finish explaining something, people will say, "You see me?" or "You get me?"

I wonder if they are equivalent to "Do you understand what I mean?"

Comment: Also, "You hear me?" or "You feel me?", to some extent.

Comment: It's a lot like "You know?"

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of "I got you"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35709/what-is-the-meaning-of-i-got-you/35710#35710)

Comment: @Sun: Where are you hearing "you see me?" (what country, what context)?  Do many people use the phrase, or just one?  If the latter, I'd warn against using it because it's an unfamiliar usage in the US and UK.  People might think that you are literally asking if they can **see** you. :p

Comment: @sequoia mcdowell : I heard from my teacher, in Vietnam :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"You get me?" most certainly means "do you understand me?"  "You see me" is unfamiliar to me (US EN), perhaps they mean "Do you see what I mean?"

In any event the context you provided (question asked after an explanation) makes it almost certain that the latter question, like the other, is used to mean "Do you understand?"

Comment: "You see me" is also unknown to me in UK English. "Do you see?" is quite common

Comment: @Colin: and even more common, perhaps, is just “You see?”  I’d be interested to know where `@`Sun is hearing “You see me?” — I could easily imagine it being common usage somewhere, especially under the influence of some other languages.

Comment: Typically "do you see?" or "you see?" is, in my understanding, short for "do you see **what I mean**?" rather than "do you see **me**?" Thank you Colin for the UK perspective and I'm curious whether PLL's guess is correct (that it's common somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than being used to mean "Do you understand?", in ordinary American speech the phrase "You get me?" is used as near-meaningless filler; that is, like "You know" it is a [*discourse particle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_particle).  ("In linguistics, a discourse particle is a lexeme or particle which has no direct semantic meaning in the context of a sentence, having rather a pragmatic function: it serves to indicate the speaker's attitude, or to structure their relationship to other participants in a conversation.")

I don't recall hearing or reading "You see me" with any relation to "Do you understand?".  I have heard it said (or have said it) in sentences like "You see me on the left in this picture."  Of course if I heard a person say "You see me?" several times in a conversation, I would class it as a discourse particle in that person's vocabulary.

Comment: This is interesting and insightful, but a bit of an overstatement, I feel.  “You get me?” seems a little bit of the way towards becoming a discourse particle — it usually carries its meaning rather less heavily than a full “Do you understand?” would — but I don’t think it’s usually, and certainly not always, lost it anywhere as much as most discourse particles have lost theirs.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume that "you get me?" *after an explanation* carries "no semantic meaning."  Depending on context, the person may be looking for a verbal response, a nod, or, as you suggest, nothing at all.  Someone may well ask "you get me?" then *wait* until they get affirmation; not answering could suggest that one is not paying attention.  Without more context, it's hard to know but I wouldn't assume "no meaning."

Comment: A person I knew used "Get me?" (rather than "You get me?") much like "You know?", i.e., would throw in a "Get me?" every two or three sentences.   I've never heard "You get me?" or "Get me?" or "You know?" used in any manner other than, primarily, verbal filler, and, secondarily, as perhaps a prompt for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both phrases mean that... Another way of use is simply stating them, instead of questioned. ex. "you get me" ...just like an affirmation of the fact that "you understand me", "you feel who I am", "you see what I'm about", "you see ME". Used this way, both phrases "you get me" and "you see me" acquire a bit more of a sensory-like meaning; perhaps more like a recognition of emotional understanding and synchronism rather than just the comprehension of what's verbally expressed.